# What approach could be taken to prove this property of Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I noticed that starting with Fibonacci numbers 2 and 3, alternating pairs of sequential Fibonacci numbers, f<sub>n</sub> and f<sub>n+1</sub> switch between having f<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup>=1 (mod f<sub>n+1</sub>) and having f<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup>= -1 (mod f<sub>n+1</sub>).

2<sup>2</sup>=1 (mod 3)
 3<sup>2</sup>= -1 (mod 5)
5<sup>2</sup>=1 (mod 8)
8<sup>2</sup> = -1 (mod 13),
and so on.

If this holds for all sequential pairs of Fibonacci numbers then one immediate result would be that all Fibonacci primes greater than 3 can only have odd Fibonacci indices. If f<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup>=1 (mod f<sub>n+1</sub>) and f<sub>n+1</sub> is prime then f<sub>n</sub> would have to equal 1 or f<sub>n+1</sub> -1, which is not possible.

I am sure that if what I am saying is correct then someone has worked it out long ago.  I am not looking for  detailed proof, just an outline of how it could be done.

I see now how the Casini identity directly relates to what I asked. I will look into the proof of that identity, which apparently is not that difficult if induction is used.

Comment: Similar to [How would one go about proving this property of Fibonacci numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4819344/89922)?

Comment: @peterwhy The question you linked to has been removed.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein Oops, at least that linked question is still accessible by this OP here.

Comment: You noticed that $f_n^2\equiv(-1)^{n-1}\!\!\pmod{\!\!\!f_{n+1}}$ (letting $f_0=0$, $f_1=1$). Now try to divide $f_n^2-(-1)^{n-1}$ by $f_{n+1}$ and see which numbers you are getting. That would help you formulate a more precise conjecture that you should then be able to prove by induction on $n$.

Comment: The deleted posting was simply linking to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities).